# PHP Write MySQL Error To File

Tags: php, mysql

How would I write a MySQL error to a file instead of displaying it to the user?

here is what I have so far...

```
if (!mysql_query($sql_query,$connection))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Success!";
```

Comment: try writing that mysql_error() to a file. how? check php file manipulation ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [error_log function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) in php for that.

```
error_log("You messed up!", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
```

Edit: so in your case this would look like the following (although i would use a different if statement)

```
if (!mysql_query($sql_query,$connection))
{
    error_log(mysql_error() . "\n", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
}
echo "Success!";
```

Comment: Don't forget the `mysql_error()` message and a `\n` since mode 3 doesn't break lines on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Use [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php), or [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)/fwrite/fclose/etc.

I often use create my own error handler with something like [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) in PHP and use [trigger_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) to capture ALL errors and write them to file.  This may be a better scenario for you; rather than writing numerous error_log()'s, you can just create an error handler function and then use trigger_error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not use die if you do not want to display your error message to the user.

Secondly, instead of using die, you must log your error message into a file. If you are using some logging library, you may output the error to some log, else you may want to have a look at File handling in PHP.

Link - http://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete

Comment: And you would have to use mysql_error() to get the error message  which is to be written to the file!